# Mongodb Nodejs gereate test data from existing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here is my code in generate.js file. I'm trying generate 100k data from an existing data array. But there's a error: BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection. Anyone has any suggestion?

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

var myobj1 = [
{ "Year" : 1998, "Cause Name" : "Suicide", "State" : "United States", "Deaths" : 31655, "Age-adjusted Death Rate" : 11, "Date Inserted" : new Date('1998-08-25T00:00:00Z') },
{ "Year" : 1999, "Cause Name" : "All causes", "State" : "United States", "Deaths" : 2319475, "Age-adjusted Death Rate" : 616, "Date Inserted" : new Date('1999-07-05T00:00:00Z') },
{ "Year" : 2000, "Cause Name" : "All causes", "State" : "Alaska", "Deaths" : 2914, "Age-adjusted Death Rate" : 869.1, "Date Inserted" : new Date('2000-08-14T00:00:00Z') },
{ "Year" : 1996, "Cause Name" : "All causes", "State" : "Alabama", "Deaths" : 44806, "Age-adjusted Death Rate" : 1009.3, "Date Inserted" : new Date('1996-10-03T00:00:00Z') },
{ "Year" : 1997, "Cause Name" : "Stroke", "State" : "Georgia", "Deaths" : 4416, "Age-adjusted Death Rate" : 72.3, "Date Inserted" : new Date('1997-06-16T00:00:00Z') }

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
 myobj1 = myobj1.concat(myobj1);
}

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("DatabaseSystem");
  
  console.log(args);
  
  dbo.collection("death").insertMany(myobj1, function(err, res) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
 db.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this `for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
 myobj1 = myobj1.concat(myobj1);
}`

Comment: to duplicate an existing sample data array

Comment: how can I generate about 100k documents from existing 5 documents above?

Comment: try to drop the collection from DB and run your code again.

Comment: still the same error, maybe I have to find another way

Comment: are you sure you dont have an _id field? Such error occur only when there is an duplicate _id field which is a 24 char hexadecimal by default.

Comment: Yes, here is the error: BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: DatabaseSystem.death index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5c874a84353c9b39d0f7d561') }

Comment: How can we avoid that?